# Load list with date value into pandas dataframe and plot activity over time

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have some Twitter data that I would like to plot activity overtime based on the type of tweet (tweet/mention/retweet).

**The data is currently loaded into a list of tuples that contains** `date` **and** `type`:

```
time = [('2014-04-13', 'tweet'),
        ('2014-04-13', 'tweet'),
        ('2014-04-13', 'mention'),
        ('2014-04-13', 'retweet'),
        ('2014-04-13', 'mention'),
        ('2014-04-13', 'tweet'),
        ('2014-04-13', 'retweet'),
        ('2014-04-13', 'mention'),
        ('2014-04-13', 'tweet'),
        ('2014-04-13', 'retweet'),
        ('2014-04-13', 'retweet'),
        ('2014-04-13', 'mention'),
        ('2014-04-13', 'tweet'),
        ('2014-04-13', 'tweet'),
        ('2014-04-13', 'tweet'),
        ('2014-04-13', 'tweet'),
        ('2014-04-13', 'mention'),
        ('2014-04-13', 'retweet'),
        ('2014-04-13', 'mention'),
        ('2014-04-13', 'tweet')]
```

**I've loaded the data into a pandas DataFrame:**

```
time_df = pd.DataFrame(time, columns=['date','time'])
```

**Now that data looks like this:**

```
         date     time
0  2014-04-13    tweet
1  2014-04-13    tweet
2  2014-04-13  mention
3  2014-04-13  retweet
4  2014-04-13  mention
...
...
...
```

However, now I'm lost when it comes to plotting this data over time.  Also, I would like to break out each type (tweet/mention/retweet) as a different color line.  I should also note that sometimes I might need to aggregate the data by day/week/month.

**Ideally I would like my plot to look similar to the following plot, except with Tweet, Mention, Retweet:**

[image: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, I think I understand what you need to do, even if this isn't explicit in your question.

Allow me to mock up some data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas
import random

tweet_types = ['tweet', 'retweet', 'mention']
index = pandas.DatetimeIndex(freq='5min', start='2014-04-13', end='2014-05-13')
tweets = [random.choice(tweet_types) for _ in range(len(index))]
time_df = pandas.DataFrame(index=index, data=tweets, columns=['tweet type'])
time_df['day'] = time_df.index.date
time_df['count'] = 1
print(time_df.head())
```

So the first few rows now look like this:

```
                     tweet type         day  count
2014-04-13 00:00:00     mention  2014-04-13      1
2014-04-13 00:05:00     mention  2014-04-13      1
2014-04-13 00:10:00       tweet  2014-04-13      1
2014-04-13 00:15:00       tweet  2014-04-13      1
2014-04-13 00:20:00     retweet  2014-04-13      1
```

I added the `count` value because we need something to total up for our daily aggregation, done here:

```
daily_counts = time_df.groupby(by=['tweet type', 'day']).count()
daily_counts_xtab = daily_counts.unstack(level='tweet type')['count']
print(daily_counts_xtab.head())
```

Which gives us...

```
tweet type  mention  retweet  tweet
day                                
2014-04-13       89      101     98
2014-04-14       98      113     77
2014-04-15       87      103     98
2014-04-16       81      107    100
2014-04-17       96       92    100
```

So then

```
daily_counts_xtab.plot()
```

Gives me:

[image]